# Responsive Site on iPhone...Load at base?

Tags: java, jquery, html, mobile-safari, responsive-design

check out http://brybell.me.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.scrollTop || window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

That is the code I am currently using to automatically hide the Safari iOS browser nav bar. However, if you look at it on your iPhone, you can see that the 2 social media buttons at the bottom are cut off and you have to scroll in order to see the full buttons.

My question is: Is there an easy way to make the page load automatically at the bottom of the page, instead of at the top? Because the whole webpage fits in the screen so the user does not need to scroll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.body.offsetHeight;
  }, 0);
});
```